# Can a school district take club funds in New York State?

Tags: school

Consider a high school in New York, with a variety of clubs for different after-school activities. Clubs that need additional funds, such as Theater and Robotics, conduct fundraisers to raise such funds (on the order of $5k-$50k).

If the administration were to remove such funds from club accounts, without stating where the money is going, would this be legal? If it is illegal, what law(s) does it violate?

Comment: [Law Stack Exchange is for educational purposes only and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner. Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship.](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Law Stack Exchange! As Trish said, your question, as it is currently written, could be understood as a request for specific legal advice, which we do not allow to avoid potential liability. Perhaps you could edit it to ask something like "Who owns funds raised by a school club?" The answer to that will likely either be the club or the school district, and from there, you should be able to determine the answer to your original question.

Answer (score -1):

### Probably legal

Almost certainly, these “clubs” are administrative divisions within the school rather than seperate legal entities. If so, then the “clubs” are not raising money, the school is and the money belongs to the school and can be used however the school sees fit.

Now, if the school raised money under false pretences - inducing people to believe it would be spent in one way and then spending it in another, that may have legal issues but it would be the donors who would have standing, not the “club”.

At a college or university, these clubs would be seperate legal entities run by the students with affiliation to the educational facility established in their constitutions and/or by contract. Then the money would belong to the club and couldn’t be taken.

Comment: I've been part of a student organization, in New York State, that raised funds, but was not, to my knowledge, an independent legal entity from the school that it was a part of (consider, for instance, the additional complications this would raise for each club to need to register and comply with the requirements to receive tax-exempt donations).  Additionally, why wouldn't the club members who donated their labor to the fundraiser have standing under a similar theory?